# Issue with completion handlers in Swift

Tags: swift, closures, completionhandler

I've to display multiple view components one at a time, only when one is displayed I want to display the 2nd one and so on. There is animation in some components. So I've this code:

```
    func addFirstElement(completion: (_ success: Bool) -> Void) {
        //code to add view element 
        completion(true)
    }

addFirstElement {(success) -> Void in
            if success {
                addSecondElement {(success) -> Void in
                    if success {
                        addThirdElement {(success) -> Void in
                            if success {
                                addForthElement {(success) -> Void in
                                    if success {
                                        addFifthElement()
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Problem is that  I see all elements getting displayed at once, instead of one at a time.
I'm kind of only partially clear on closures, so I am not sure the code I have is correct.

Comment: use timer delay before every `if success`

Comment: it is adding so fast that you think it is all at once, it is just quick

Answer (score 0):

unless you have some lengthy operation in the creation of each component, then of course it will appear like they are all appearing at once.

If you want to see them appearing sequentially, introduce an operation that takes some time into each controller creation.

If you want the next controller to appear when the previous animation has completed, then you need to use the completion handler of the animation

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(animationDuration, animations: {
    // animation
    }, completion: {(finished:Bool) in
        // load up the next view
})
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, seems like animation is the issue. Where I've comment "//code to add view element ", has animation for some type of elements. So if the first element has animation, and second doesnt, I want second one to appear after the first ones animation is complete. Looks like I'll have to use completion handler of animation.